# Kubernetes - Deleting petsets doesn't delete pods

Tags: kubernetes

I am in an environment where we are still using petsets. When I run the following command :

```
kubectl delete petsets <petset-name>
```

The petset is deleted but the pods(pets) associated with it are not deleted. When I tried this locally on minikube using statefulsets, the statefulsets as well as pods are getting deleted. Is it the behaviour of petsets? or Is it a bug with petsets or my environment? Is there a way to debug this? Because when I checked the documentation here : [petsets](https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/petset/#deleting-a-petset), it seems the pods should have been deleted!?

Comment: Do you have any issues with manual deletion?? Use the command kubectl delete  pod <pod-name> or kubectl delete  pods <pods-list>

Comment: @Sri - I would not prefer to do manual deletion. The whole point of controllers is that it should be able to take care of deletions on its own. thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using an old version of kubernetes that is affected by [issue 27438](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/27438). Upgrade to 1.5. (See `kubectl version`)